# Bypass the .submit() handler

Tags: jquery

I have an event handler for a form submittal that needs to do some work. That work includes making an ajax call to perform some very specific validations. Because of the asynchronous nature, my intent was to `preventDefault` at the top of the event handler and, if everything went well, submit the form "manually" by triggering the `submit()` method.

Of course, that drops me into a loop. If I submit and all goes well, then the submit event handler is called when I resubmit. Is there any way to bypass the handler when I trigger the submit manually?

I should add that my geek karma is on empty today so I may be making this much harder than it has to be. If there's a dead simple solution for what I'm trying to do, I'd love to hear it.

I should add that I've put a working solution in place by simply making the jQuery `$.ajax` call synchronous, but I can't help feeling like there's a more effective way of getting this done that I'm just not seeing today.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Don't place a submit button on the form, place a button bound as a "validation" mechanism that (when correct) *eventually* submits.</strike>

As far as backwards-compatibility, add a submit button, then use jQuery to replace the button with one of your custom-bound buttons (so in the event they don't support javascript they can still proceed). Afterall, the server should have input validation(s) anyways for these situations/hacking of the form.

Having re-thought it, move your validation logic's trigger around. Bind to the click event of the submit button. This allows you to intervene just before the `submit()` is called. This event should also **always** return false, as you want to wait for the AJAX response to truly validate weather the form should submit or not.

From there, await the AJAX response back, and call submit when all is well.

In regards to backwards-compatibility, you should still have this validation logic server-side in the event that:

1. there is no javascript support (maybe they're using NoScript plugin?)
2. The use feels like circumventing the form logic and starts hi-jacking the submission data.
3. Any other (in)valid reason why the AJAX validation may not be done and catch and problems.

Comment: we were thinking of the same solution  +1

Comment: Do you know, off the top of your head, whether the click event capture a press of the `Enter` key? I want to be sure I capture all means of submitting the form.

Comment: @Rob: Should, thought testing is the best way. Feel free to pop that jsfiddle demo up in various browsers and try hitting enter. -- Follow-up: Latest chrome, FF6, IE9 all trigger the button's click event on enter while in the input field.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<form id="my-form">
    <!-- your fields... -->
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
var myForm = $('#my-form');

myForm.on('submit', function(e, skipValidation) {
    if(skipValidation) {
        return;
    }

    yourAjaxValidation().then(function(){
        myForm.trigger('submit', [true]);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type=button onclick="javascript:myFunct();return false;">

function myFunct(){

    $.post('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
         //do validation of ajax response
         if(all is good){
                $('#myForm').submit();
         }
    });

}
```

Comment: Given AJAX is async, a simple "yes/no" is not possible within that "submit thread". This is the whole issue.

Comment: it will not call the function when the form is submitted.  re-read the code. i am using the onclick event,  not onsubmit...  edit: someone deleted their comment

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is "unlock" the function.

```
var done = false;

function AjaxCallback()
{
  done = true;
  document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}

function PerformAjax()
{
  if (!done)
  {
    // perform ajax here
    return false;
  }
  else
    return true;
}

<form id="myForm" onsubmit="javascript: return PerformAjax();">
```

Comment: You're still assuming a return can carry through from the AJAX "success thread" back on through to the original form "submit catch thread". You also have an infinite loop, basically mimicking what the OP was insinuating.

Comment: What? The form will be submitted the first time, perform the ajax, return false - it will not submit. When the ajax finishes, it will set `done` to true, and then submit the form again. This time the form will successfully submit, because `done` is true, and `PerformAjax` will return true.

Comment: Indeed, it did elude me as I didn't see done set to true anywhere (though I now realize it's set within the AJAX call. My mistake. Though I could hit ESC on the AJAX call, manipulate the form, and re-submit and bypass the "lock".

Comment: Hmm true, or even `javascript: done = true; void 0;` into the URL bar would bypass too.. I like your solution above better.